# Unit testing entity frameworks identity id is zero

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

```
[TestMethod()]
[Description("Policies: AddReconciliationForDevice")]
public void PL210102()
{
  // arrange
  IDeviceDataFactory dataFactory = new DeviceDataFactoryMock();
  PoliciesLogic target = new PoliciesLogic(dataFactory);
  var po = new PrivateObject(target);
  new PoliciesLogic_Accessor(po)._queueLogic = new QueuesLogic(dataFactory);
  DeviceDataRepositoryMock repository = dataFactory.Create() as DeviceDataRepositoryMock;
  DeviceEntitiesMock model = repository.Entities;
  var changeHelper = new SaveChangesHelper(model);

  //Act
  target.AddReconciliationForDevice(1, new DateTime(2010,01,01));

  // assert;
  Assert.AreEqual(2, changeHelper.Snapshots.Count());
  Assert.AreEqual(1, changeHelper.Snapshots[1].PackageTemplates.Count());
  Assert.AreEqual("Reconcile", changeHelper.Snapshots[1].PackageTemplates.ElementAt(0).Name);
  Assert.AreEqual((int)EnumPackageItemTemplatesCommand.ReconcileData, changeHelper.Snapshots[1].PackageItemTemplates.ElementAt(0).CommandTypeId);
  Assert.AreEqual(1, changeHelper.Snapshots[1].Packages.Count());
  Assert.AreEqual(1, changeHelper.Snapshots[1].PackageItems.Count());
  Assert.AreEqual(1, changeHelper.Snapshots[1].Queues.Count());
  Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2010, 01, 01), changeHelper.Snapshots[1].Queues.ElementAt(0).EarliestExecutionTime);
}
```

I am trying to unit test a data insert using entity frameworks. I have set up a mock of my data repository, and have set up a helper that creates a snapshot each time the repository is saved, that can track the changes.

My issue is that within the method being tested:

```
public void AddReconciliationForDevice(int deviceId, DateTime timeToSend)
{
  if (deviceId <= 0) throw new ArgumentException(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Invalid deviceId value '{0}' seen", deviceId));
  using (IDeviceData repository = DataFactory.Create())
  {
    List<int> devList = new List<int>();
    devList.Add(deviceId);

    // Add PackageTemplate
    var pt = AddPackageTemplate("Reconcile", 28, repository);
    // Add PackageItemTemplate
    var pit = AddPackageItemTemplate(pt, null, repository, EnumPackageItemTemplatesCommand.ReconcileData, 1);
    // Add package
    List<Package> packList = AddPackage(pt, devList, repository, false);
    // Add PackageItem
    AddPackageItem(pit, packList.ElementAt(0), repository);
    // Saves to get packageTemplateId
    repository.SaveChanges();
    // Adds queue
    _queueLogic.AddQueue(pt.Id, deviceId, timeToSend);
  }
}
```

The `Id` for `pt` is always zero, I cant work out if ef is assiging zero as the first id or this is just the default value fior an integer. The `AddQueue` method throws an error if pt.id is zero, so my test fails.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most definitely because the default value of integer is 0, since you've mocked the repository.

I think you also should mock the `_queuesLogic` as well, instead of using a real instance in your test method:

```
new PoliciesLogic_Accessor(po)._queueLogic = new QueuesLogic(dataFactory);//use a mock instead of doing a new
```

This way, you wouldn't have to worry about the id being zero or not.

Comment: Good thinking, because Ive already tested that method seperately so dont need to worry about it here